# putting a bottom border underneath a bullet point

Tags: html, css

I want my last list to have an underline that goes all the way to the left margin, not just where the content starts. I tried using the "list-style-position: inside;" tag, but all it does is move the bullet point over to the right, it doesn't move the underline to the left. Anyone help?

```
<li class="end">content</li> 

.end{
border-bottom:1px solid black;
margin-bottom:-1px;}
```

Comment: I am making a resume online and I want to separate sections (experience from activities) but when I put a bottom border underneath my last bullet point, it starts the border at the first letter, not against the left margin side.

Comment: How exactly would I do this? I am self-teaching myself code from codeacademy and I am extremely new...sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just give the `<ul>` the border as so: [**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/RMm73/2/).

```
ul {
border-bottom:5px solid black;
}
```

Another option..

As opposed to merely giving the last list item a bottom border, you can simply place a `<hr>` proceeding the list. Doing this, you avoid the original issue regarding the margin.

Example for this, [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/RMm73/). This is the ***better*** option..

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to underline your bullets, this will do it:

```
ul li {
  list-style:none;
  border-bottom: #000 solid 1px;
}

ul li:before {
  content: '\2022';
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/ff52L/) with the code

**EDIT**
If you're looking to underline the list, this will do it:

```
ul {
  border-bottom: #000 solid 1px;
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/ff52L/1/) with the code